# Title of an anime with children quarantined in a city block?

Tags: guilty-crown

This is all I can remember:

It's an anime series with some SF or future theme. The government has the ability to close off a very large city-block with walls that can move and destroy buildings. Behind these walls, they have defenses which can kill anyone who tries to leave the quarantined area. As far as I know, there was some form of virus, but the surviving children were not contaminated.

As far as I know, it's about a high-schooler who has to survive in this quarantine and has to form a society to survive. At first, the leader wanted to be more democratic, but then his girlfriend gets killed which turns him into become a hard-line dictator. In the end (I think, not sure), they build enough resources to make an attempt to escape.

I'd like to know the title of this series. For some reason, the new Valvrave anime reminds me of this series.

I hope I've given you enough information to find the title.

Comment: Do you know a time period when it might have aired? or when did you watch it?

Comment: I wish I could. I thought I'd seen it on DVD(1999). But it could have been 1 of my earlier complete downloads(2002). At first I thought it was Infinite Ryvius, but that one was set in space, in a spaceship.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Guilty Crown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guilty_Crown)

[image]

Comment: Hiya, thanks for that title. But it's not the title I was looking for. The main character didn't have powers as far as I remember.

Comment: hmm then i gotta remember which 1 it was since i remember the anime you are describing

Comment: lol, also wracking my brain over here. Looking through my old DVD's right now. XD I can see the images vividly, but just can't seem to remember the title.

Comment: @Kat: This is the closest match for the recent years anime.

Comment: @Kat http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Guilty_Crown_episodes you might wanna read the episode descriptions to see if it really isnt this anime

Comment: Downloading it now. Really thought that the main character didn't have any powers. Hoping for the best.

Comment: Also reading the episode link, hopefully that'll jog my memory.

Comment: Thanks! It is the correct answer, sorry for having a bad memory. Only thing I could connect to Guilty Crown at first was mechas and resistance, a crappy lead character with power and an idol girl. Thank you for helping me. *starts to replace harddrive in head*

Comment: @Kat No problem glad we could help you

Answer (score 1):

[Betterman](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=350)?

From Anime News Network:

> A deadly virus known as "Algernon" has attacked humanity with vicious meaning. At the forefront of the battle is the mystifying Akamatsu Industries – disguised as a heavy machine factory in Tokyo, this undercover organization uses neural enhanced weapons known as NeuroNoids to battle Algernon.